# Android Google api v2 navigation route map without using parsing

Tags: android

I want to create a route map navigation in Android google map v2 along with all those details which google provides( like at this crossing you have to turn left). I know this can be done using a parsing techniques i have done that but what im looking for is, is there any new method predefined within android v2 google map which will give all these details and will show the route map within two points.

Again Im mentioning it **not using the JSON parsing technique.** anything newly implemented for v2

Any sample projects or examples is very much helpful.

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25765972/3020568

Answer (score 1):

Without using json parsing technique to draw routes can be done  by one method linking to google navigation by doing stuff like this.

```
String address = marker.getTitle();
Intent intent;
if (address == null) {
LatLng pt = marker.getPosition();           
String lat = Double.toString(pt.latitude); //this i mentioned with current location
String lng = Double.toString(pt.longitude);
intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + lat + "," + lng));
```

However for Google map direction, json parsing is best.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is only the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=en) available for a route response, which includes JSON parsing.